# Rack number in hadoop slaves file?

Tags: hadoop

In the slaves file under config directory of Hadoop, I remember rack number can be assigned as well but I am having a hard time to confirm or to find an example. Can someone help?

Comment: Maybe I am confused? It looks like I need to provide some kind of script returning rack number given an IP or hostname? And then specify the path of the script in net.topology.script.file.name parameter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A **slave** file doesn't contain the rack number, it has a list of machines (one per line) that each run a datanode and a tasktracker. Hadoop can be made rack aware using a script or a command, [here](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/cluster_setup.html#Hadoop+Rack+Awareness) is more information on it.